# Number of ways to reach the root node in a binary graph?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm

In how many ways can we reach the top layer from bottom layer in the graph structure below? Is their any recursive definition to this problem? Assume that we can't be in the same layer after a step, we are always moving towards to the root node or peak.

```
  O
 O O
O O O
```

Here n=3 (#nodes in bottom layer = height of the graph+1). For this graph, we have 4 ways to move from bottom layer to peak. How can we generalize this to any 'n'? Also, how can we do this using dynamic programming?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tell us how you have already attempted to solve the problem.

Comment: We do not see edges... you can only go "up" to the node which is very near? For example left-bottom node can only reach left-middle node?

Comment: nope sir...I already graduated! :)

Comment: My follow-on comment still stands; what have you done to try to solve the problem at hand?

Comment: It looks like it's going to be 2^(n-1)

Comment: we can move from any node to its upper left or upper right node only! For example, in above graph, if we start at middle node in bottom layer, we can go to any node in second layer, whereas if we start at extreme corners, we stick to the nodes along the sides of triangle. I tried using top down approach, starting from root, we have 2 ways to go to layer below it, which always have 2 nodes. Now, we can have two triangular subtrees. But for some reason, i'm not able to generalize it.

Comment: Based on that description, it's not really a binary graph.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that from a given node you can only climb up-left or up-right, then the result seems to be 2^N, where N is the tree height.

Explanation: The number of paths from node (i,j) is c(i,j)=c(i-1,j-1)+c(i-1,j). This produces the [pascal triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), where every level N has the sum 2^N.

Comment: Are you counting the root as a height of 1 or 0?

Comment: In my formula the root is level 0

Comment: OP says example tree is height of 3

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Actually he says n=3=height+1

Comment: `n` is still three, so we can do this all day long.  Perhaps you can use a different letter than the one the OP is using.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I see. Then it's either 2^(n-1) or 2^N, where N is the tree height.

Comment: I tried it for height of 3 (thus n=4) and the result is 14

Comment: @libik: Consider the 4 bottom nodes in a tree of height 3. The nodes at the 2 ends can only climb in one way. the two middle nodes have 3 different ways to climb. Therefore you have a total of 8 ways to climb from the bottom level up to the root.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - yes, that means the 2^depth is false

Answer (score 0):

Another point of view:
Let's call c(n) the number of ways which lead to the top from the layer of depth n, thus we have c(0)=1. Since each node in the n-1 layer can be reached by two different ways from layer n (from the left or from the right), we have c(n) = 2*c(n-1). Combining this with c(0)=1 leads to c(n)=2^n.